# appending log to a file in unix but with different name each day

Tags: unix

i am appending the output of a cron job into a file like below

```
10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /home/mydir/shellScript.sh >> /home/mydir/shellScript.log 2>&1
```

but the file size is keep on increasing, i want to do either of the below things.

1)**create a new file after reaching certain size**
2)**create a new file each day of its run**

we need to maintain the file for at least 15  days due to audit reasons.can someone help on this,thanks in advance.

Comment: For generating new file try `> /home/mydir/shellScript_$(date '+%Y%m%d').log`

Comment: not working for cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved using below:

10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /home/mydir/shellScript.sh >> /home/mydir/shellScript_`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log 2>&1